# Error in using @dataclass with inheritance

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

```
@dataclass
class base:
    data_dir: Path = Path(__file__).parents[1] / 'data'
    models_dir: Path = data_dir / 'models'

@dataclass
class field(base):
    id: str
    data_source: str  # can be a csv file or a database
    df: pd.DataFrame  # dataframe containing field information

    def get_field(self):
        pass
```

In the code above, I get this error:
`TypeError: non-default argument 'id' follows default argument`

How can I fix this?

Comment: By moving the definition of the argument with a default value to before all those that do not.

Comment: The documentation ("TypeError will be raised if a field without a default value follows a field with a default value. **This is true either when this occurs in a single class, or as a result of class inheritance.**") implies you simply cannot define non-default fields in a subclass of a field with default-valued fields.

Comment: @martineau, but how is that done here? - ah, \@chepner said it.  That seems kinda bizarre to me.  So he has to give all of his fields default values then, eh?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken and based my comment strictly on the error message.